# What encryption protocol is used by paragonie/Halite library by default?

Tags: php, security, encryption, libsodium

We're going to implement encryption between php server and python server. 
We decided to use paragonie/halite library (based on libsodium) on our php part. Python guy are asking what exact protocol from libsodium they should implement. And I don't know what to say them.

What encryption protocol is used by Halite library by default?

Comment: I don't think so halite available for python.

Comment: But halite is a wrapper for libsodium. Libsodium is available on python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What encryption protocol is used by Halite library by default?

Not only is it by default, but it's the only option: XSalsa20.

https://github.com/paragonie/halite/blob/master/doc/Primitives.md

Comment: Thank you! That was quite obvious from the sources, but I missed this. Thanks again.

Comment: Now I have other problem that guy on python side don't understand how to decrypt an encryptredString. Seems XSalsa20 requires also nonce to be sent, but I'm getting only an encrypted string from Halite...

Comment: No, Halite packages the nonce, HKDF salt, and ciphertext all in one string.